# Find group isomorphic to the quotient group

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

I'm working on a few problems of a similar type. I'm pretty confident I got the right answer but I'm not sure how to provide satisfiable enough proof that the answer is correct. **I'd be glad if you could point out any "holes" in my arguments, if there are any.** Thanks.

Let's assume the problem is as follows:

> Find a group isomorphic to the group $(G, \cdot)/H$, where $$G =
> \left \{
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> r & q & 0 \\
> f & g & 1 
> \end{pmatrix} \mid q \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus\{0\}\,,\,\, r \in \mathbb{R}\,,\,\,  f,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]\,,\,\, g(5) = 0 \right \}
> \text{,}$$
>   $$H =
> \left \{
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 & 0 \\
> r & 1 & 0 \\
> f & g & 1 
> \end{pmatrix} \mid r \in \mathbb{R}\,,\,\,  f,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]\,,\,\, g(5) = f(5) = 0 \right \}\text{.}
> $$

My hypothesis is that $(G, \cdot)/H \cong (K, \times)$ where $(K, \times) = (\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \cdot) \times (\mathbb{R}, +)$. Let's assume an surjective homomorphism $\alpha : (G, \cdot) \longrightarrow K$ is defined by the following formula:
$$\alpha\left (
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
r & q & 0 \\
f & g & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \right ) = (q, f(5))\text{.}$$

To prove $\alpha$ is a surjective homomorphisum we show:

1. $\alpha$ is a homomorphism: $$\alpha\left (
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   r & q & 0 \\
   f & g & 1 
   \end{pmatrix} \cdot
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   \bar{r} & \bar{q} & 0 \\
   \bar{f} & \bar{g} & 1 
   \end{pmatrix} \right ) = \alpha\left (
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   r+q\bar{r} & q\bar{q} & 0 \\
   f + g\bar{r} + \bar{f} & g\bar{q}+\bar{g} & 1 
   \end{pmatrix} \right) = (q\bar{q},(f+g\bar{r}+\bar{f})(5)) = (q\bar{q}, (f+\bar{f})(5))$$ $$\alpha\left(
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   r & q & 0 \\
   f & g & 1 
   \end{pmatrix}
   \right)\times \alpha\left(
   \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   \bar{r} & \bar{q} & 0 \\
   \bar{f} & \bar{g} & 1 
   \end{pmatrix}
   \right)= (q, f(5)) \times (\bar{q},\bar{f}(5)) = (q\bar{q}, f(5) + \bar{f}(5)) = (q\bar{q}, (f + \bar{f})(5))$$
2. $\alpha$ is surjective: given any $(q', r') \in K$ we put $q = q'$ and $f = x + (r' - 5)$.

Now we show that $H = Ker(\alpha)$:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
r & q & 0 \\
f & g & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\in Ker(\alpha) \Longleftrightarrow \alpha \left(
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
r & q & 0 \\
f & g & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\right)= (1,0) \Longleftrightarrow q = 1 \wedge f(5) = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
r & q & 0 \\
f & g & 1 
\end{pmatrix} \in H
$$
Thus, as per the first isomorphism theorem, $img(\alpha) \cong (G,\cdot)/H$. As $\alpha$ is surjective $img(\alpha) = K$, which proves our initial hypothesis $(G, \cdot)/H \cong (K, \times)$.

Comment: Looks good to me. Who on earth forced you to look at this crazy group? One typo in the last line where you say $f(g) = 5$ when of course you mean $f(5) = 0$.

Comment: My condolences for having gone through all this. Your solution looks perfect to me. A minor note; for surjectivity of $\alpha$ you might as well take $f=r'$ in stead of $f=(x-5)+r'$, though both are fine of course.

Comment: Curious where this comes from. Similar solvable groups ($3\times 3$ triangular matrices with diagonal $(1,\ast,1)$) were considered by Ph. Hall in the fifties.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo and for suggesting using $f=r'$ for the surjection. @YCor We were solving problems like this during my algebra course at my university and a similar one will be most likely part of my final exam.